# How to use $lookup in a project where there are multiple databases?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, aggregation-framework

### Here's my product.model.js

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var Schema = mongoose.Schema; var ObjectId = mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId;

const ProductModel = new Schema(
    {
        name: {
            type: String
        },
        //hidden code for better viewing
        policyId: {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId
        }
    },
    {
        strict: false,
        timestamps: true
    }
);

const myDB = mongoose.connection.useDb('SampleDB'); 
module.exports = myDB.model('bf-product', ProductModel);
```

### Here's my return-policy.model.js

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var ObjectId = mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId;

const ReturnPolicyModel = new Schema(
    {
        name: {
            type: String
        },
        description: {
            type: String
        },
        addedById: {
            type: String
        },
        status: {type: Number, default: 1}
    },
    {
        strict: false,
        timestamps: true
    }
);

const myDB = mongoose.connection.useDb('SampleDB');
module.exports = myDB.model('bf-return-pol', ReturnPolicyModel);
```

Here's the query I'm running

```
const Product = require('../models/product.model');
let products = await Product.aggregate([
        {
          $lookup:
            {
              from: "bf-return-pol",
              localField: "policyId",
              foreignField: "_id",
              as: "policies"
            }
       }
    ])

console.log(products)
```

When I run the query, policies always returns empty. I think the issue is because of the project using multiple databases, as I had a similar issue with paths with the populate keyword. So my question is this, how can I run the query as both the collections are in the same db?

### product collection

[image: product collection]

### return-policy collection

[image: return-policy collection]

**EDIT:** The issue seemed to be that the collection was named as "bf-return-pols" and once I changed the from field in lookup, I could get the results.

Comment: In your data model, "policyId" is a `string` while the default `_id` field is a `BSON ObjectId`. A string is not an ObjectId.

Comment: I changed the policyId to a type mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, yet the policies is empty.

Comment: The schema matters little, because Mongo is schemaless, the _values_ in your collection should `ObjectId`s. Changing the model now won't your change existing data, only new data.

Comment: I deleted the old collection entries and inserted a few entries again. Check the new pictures.